# Spark set parallelism without repartitioning

Tags: scala, parallel-processing, apache-spark-sql

I'm working with spark 1.6 in `local[N]` (with N <= #available cores) mode doing some expensive computations inside an UDF on a dataframe consisting of 1 partition only (i.e. read from a Hive table). Something like this:

```
val data = sc.parallelize(0 to 1000,1).toDF("ID") // the source data (from Hive table) with 1 partition
val expensiveCalc = udf((i:Int) => {Thread.sleep(100);i}) // expensive dummy UDF
val computed = data.withColumn("dummy",expensiveCalc($"ID")) // apply udf
computed.collect() // trigger action
```

If I run my code, only 1 core is working (as there is only 1 task created). I can achieve full parallelism by re-partitioning my dataframe into (at least) N partitions, such that at least N tasks are created using `data.repartition(N)` before applying my UDF.

Is there a way to achieve parallelism in the above code without changing the number of partitions?

Comment: So, the question is how to apply that udf in parallel to the data with only one partition?

Comment: why repartition is out of the question?

Comment: @maasg re-partitioning is not out of question, I just thought that there is a more direct way to specify the degree of parallelism.. re-partitioning seems somehow overkill

Comment: Spark unit of parallelism is a 'partition'. There are ways to do what you ask, like `mapPartitions` but that's a workaround outside of spark model, not a "parallelism setting" as you're requesting.